# seaborn plot from total

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, seaborn

I have the following data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group': ['Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Blue', 'Blue', 'Blue'],
                   'valueA_found': [10, 40, 50, 20, 50, 70],
                   'valueA_total': [100,200, 210, 100, 200, 210],
                  'date': ['2017-01-01', '2017-02-01', '2017-03-01', '2017-01-01', '2017-02-01', '2017-03-01']})
```

and can create a plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,8))
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
g = sns.barplot(x="date", y="valueA_found", hue="group", data=df)
# g.set_yscale('log')
g.set_xticklabels(df.date, rotation=45)
g.set(xlabel='date', ylabel='value from total')
```

But, I  would rather like to see below per each point in time: 
[image]
as you can see per each model valueA_found is plotted as a bar and the total is plotted as a single bar.

Initially suggested, it would also be possible to plot the total as a line - but as outlined in the comments it is probably better to produce a bar as well. valueA_total i.e. the total should be the same per group per month.

Comment: What is ValueB? Is the purpose to plot a pink line on top of the bars?

Comment: It does not need to be pink. Context: the values are absolute values from a classification machine learning problem. Groups constituted different models. I want to evaluate these models over time and want to display how many valueA are found from the total of valueB per model and month.

Comment: My comment was rather meant to encourage you to explain what you want in the question. E.g. the word "line" does not even appear in it. Also, what are the requirements of that line? This is especially important since connecting points on a categorical plot may not seem very intuitive, even less if independent groups are to be connected(if this is what you want?); the better you explain what you're after, the higher the chances of obtaining a satisfying answer.

Comment: I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Since in the picture you now have only one group, I wouldn't know what to do with the second group now. I could imagine that you want something like shown in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTlhL.png). If this is the case I could provide that as an answer.

Comment: An answer to what you linked in the image would be great. This looks like a possible answer to what I asked for. I just wonder if it is better to display the total once per group like you did or once per time window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option might be to plot the total values in a desaturated/more transparent bar plot behind the first dataset.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn.apionly as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'group': ['Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Blue', 'Blue', 'Blue'],
                   'valueA': [10, 40, 50, 20, 50, 70],
                   'valueB': [100,200, 210, 100, 200, 210],
                  'date': ['2017-01-01', '2017-02-01', '2017-03-01', 
                           '2017-01-01', '2017-02-01', '2017-03-01']})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,4))

sns.barplot(x="date", y="valueB", hue="group", data=df, 
            ax=ax, palette={"Red":"#f3c4c4","Blue":"#c5d6f2" }, alpha=0.6)
sns.barplot(x="date", y="valueA", hue="group", data=df, 
            ax=ax, palette={"Red":"#d40000","Blue":"#0044aa" })


ax.set_xticklabels(df.date, rotation=45)
ax.set(xlabel='date', ylabel='value from total')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Or just putting one bar plot in the background, assuming that the totals of each group are always the same:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn.apionly as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'group': ['Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Blue', 'Blue', 'Blue'],
                   'valueA': [10, 40, 50, 20, 50, 70],
                   'valueB': [100,200, 210, 100, 200, 210],
                  'date': ['2017-01-01', '2017-02-01', '2017-03-01', 
                           '2017-01-01', '2017-02-01', '2017-03-01']})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,4))

sns.barplot(x="date", y="valueB", data=df[df.group=="Red"], 
            ax=ax,  color="#e7e2e8", label="total")
sns.barplot(x="date", y="valueA", hue="group", data=df, 
            ax=ax, palette={"Red":"#d40000","Blue":"#0044aa" })


ax.set_xticklabels(df.date, rotation=45)
ax.set(xlabel='date', ylabel='value from total')

plt.show()
```

[image]